# VBA click a specific button

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a program to access a website, type in a zip code, add the zip code then press a button to get to the next page. My code is below.

Now I'm stuck on this page and can't get the program to click on the "Property" tab and go to the next page I want to see. Can I get any help on clicking on this button?

I've tried `.GetElementsbyID("").click` but that doesn't seem to work...

Web page code around the button I want to press:

```
<span class="geographymap-span-tab" id="tab_PROPERTY_PAGE" onclick="showSearchTypeSection('PROPERTY_PAGE','PROPERTY')"><img id="PROPERTY_PAGE_IMG" src="/list/images/PROPERTY_PAGE_2.gif" alt="property" width="80" height="29" border="0" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('PROPERTY_PAGE')" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore('PROPERTY_PAGE')"></span>
```

My code thus far is below:

```
Sub TestProgram()

Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.Navigate "http://www.listsource.com/build.marketing.list"

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "www.listsource.com is loading. Thanks and Gig 'em..."
 '   Application.StatusBar = False

' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

'Focus on the drop down menu
IE.document.getElementByID("locator").Focus
'Select zip code which happens to be the 19th item
IE.document.getElementByID("locator").selectedIndex = 19
'Get to the right page based on that selection
IE.document.getElementByID("locator").FireEvent ("onchange")

'input zipcode

 Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."

    Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")

    i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "zipTextArea" Then

            ' Set text for search
            objCollection(i).Value = "75225"

        Else
            If objCollection(i).Type = "button" And _
               objCollection(i).Name = "addZip" Then

                ' "Search" button is found
                Set objElement = objCollection(i)

            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

' pull all elements that are buttons
Set objInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

'click button
For Each ele In objInputs
   If ele.Name Like "addZip" Then
      ele.Click
 End If
Next


    ' Wait while IE re-loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop


' FIND OUT total # of SFR in each given zip code
' Click on "Property" button


End Sub
```

What can I add to click on the Property Tab?

Comment: You may need to set the variable for ele.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could check the form (searchform) for all elements named "addzip" and click on the first it encounters.

```
'(Dim frm as object)
'(Dim btnAdd as object)

Set frm = IE.document.forms("searchform")   
Set btnAdd = frm.all("addzip")(0)   
btnAdd.click
```